# 8 numbers/letters encoding from Texas Instrument low energy bluetooth

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

I'm getting these values from a low energy bluetooth device:

```
This is the characteristic <26282a2c 2e303234 36383a3c 3e404244 46484a4c>
```

I'm getting these values with a simple:

```
NSLog("%@",characteristic.value)
```

I have no idea what format this is in, and that makes me think that that is why my conversions later in the code are producing a static result.

This is the code I'm using later to hold these values in an array `xval`

```
[characteristic.value getBytes:&xval length:TI_KEYFOB_ACCEL_READ_LEN];
```

Like I said it's producing a static result which makes me think the format of these values are unintelligable. Not sure if there's a simple way to refer to these values or "unencript" them so to speak. Help me out if you can.

Comment: Do you know at least what is supposed to be in the value "after translation"?

Comment: Try this: `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:xval encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Comment: @Bannings That assumes the data actually represents a string. Given that data is simply a series of bytes where each is 2 more than the previous byte, I doubt it is a UTF-8 encoded string.

Comment: @rmaddy: Indeed, except if the message is `&(*,.02468:<>@BDFHJL` (I tried with te NSUTF8Encoding).

Comment: @Larme Yes, you get a string with the data in the question. But when the sequence goes beyond `7f` it will no longer be a valid UTF-8 string.

Comment: @Bannings guess I should have mentioned the array is of uint8. xcode won't compile saying implicit conversion of non-objective pointer type 'UInt8' to NSData

Comment: @Doug Maybe you should use `characteristic.value` instead of using `xval`.

Comment: @Bannings some of the values I got back: `.02468:<>@BDFHJLNPRT`, `VXZ\^bdfhjlnprtvxz|` and a lot of `(null)` and this repeats throughout. The first value was exactly the one you suspected, but still not sure what this means, or what format it's in, looks like it's been converted in the wrong way.

Comment: @Doug I think it's not a UTF-8 encoded string.